# Visual Studio Code, code command does not start new file

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm having an issue where if I do `code <filename>` where the file does not already exist, it does not create a new file.

Normally, vscode would (almost) create a new file, I could write some code, and then save it and it would appear in my file manager. But this just stopped working.

I had a look through all my extensions and uninstalled all the recent extensions. I've reinstalled vscode, still no luck.

I am using windows with wsl, this affects me when running vscode both in windows and in wsl.

Did some googling around, can't find anything useful. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what caused this in case anyone else is having the same problem.

I installed Rust in windows and that seemed to have messed up the `code` command.

Sorry, can't remember which version it was, I just uninstalled it on windows and noticed that it fixed it.

(p.s: Rust is great, but I have it installed in WSL so don't need it in windows.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using npm on windows, you can install touch by running `npm i -g touch` and creating a folder in a specific location by navigating in the location and creating by `mkdir <foldername>` navigating inside it and using `touch <filename>`. From there you can simply launch VS Code by running code . in that folder namespace

If you are using WSL (Ubuntu), it comes preinstalled and you can run `mkdir <foldername> && touch <filename> && code .`

Not exactly what you are looking for but it can work!